# Mutex locking hash map reduces performance

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, hashtable, mutex

I have a program written in C to count frequencies of words in a file using multiple threads.
I expect the program to get faster as I add threads but performance gets slower as I add threads. 
I have debugged the issue down to the mutex locking I have at the hash table section of my code which the only shared variable I am using. 
How can I use locks properly to ensure better performance?

```
//Tokenize file contents
char **tokens=tokenizeFileContents(fileContent);

//Loop to iterate over all tokens and store frequencies
while(1){
    if(tokens[index]==NULL){
        break;
    }
    char * token=tokens[index];


    pthread_mutex_lock(&hashTable_mutex);
    if(ht_get(ht,token)==NULL){

        ht_set(ht,token,"1");

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&hashTable_mutex);
    }

    else{
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&hashTable_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&hashTable_write_mutex);
        int count=atoi(ht_get(ht,token))+1;
        char buf[32];
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", count);
        ht_set(ht,token,buf);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&hashTable_write_mutex);
    }
    index++;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid your program is subject to a number of other race conditions.  Pretending that you can do a `ht_get()` with only a `hashTable_write_mutex` is going to backfire, where the hash table grows in size and moves all its elements around in the first case of your if.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use locks properly to ensure better performance?

In your particular task it looks to be most efficient for each thread to populate its own hash map with no mutex locking. When threads complete, aggregate their hash tables into a total one (sum up values for matching hash map keys).

You may also want to partition your input data to give each thread its own chunk, so that they don't compete for reading the next element from the input data.

Comment: That is helpful. How would I aggregate each hash table into a total one?
And yes I am handing chunks of the file to each thread

Comment: @ichaudry Your hash maps are counts/frequencies of your elements (hash map keys). To aggregate them, iterate over all element-count pairs in each hash table, create the corresponding element in the total hash map with count 0 if it doesn't exists yet, and then add to that total element count the individual element count. It is like outer join with sum aggregation.